# Código PHP com mensagem de erro fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
$fp=@fopen('test','r');
@fread($fp,2000);
@fclose($fp); 
?>
```

com o seguinte erro:

> fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given :4

*mesmo quando retiro os @ o erro persiste!

Comment: Pela mensagem de erro parece que o arquivo não foi encontrado ... você deveria remover essas arrobas do código. o `fread()` nem deve funcionar.

Comment: @rray mesmo sem as arrobas (@) ele continua dando o mesmo erro.

Comment: O nome do arquivo e o caminho estão corretos?

Comment: Não coloque `@` a função é suprimir erros, raros casos, eu não uso por exemplo

Comment: test.ext, acho que falta a extensão do arquivo

Comment: Coloque todo o erro na sua pergunta, e coloque todo o código, não suprime nada! tudo é importante!

Comment: Esta tudo na pergunta, o erro persiste mesmo retirando os '@', quanto a extensão, então, peguei esse código bruto, só compilei através de um compilador online.

Comment: Na máquina local funciona esse código?

Comment: Esse tipo de erro costuma gerar um arquivo de erro enorme se não colocar um if file exist, caso esteja em um while

Comment: Seu código sem a extensão do arquivo gerou esses erros no meu servidor: [02-Oct-2017 07:53:31 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  fopen(test): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in ... on line 3
[02-Oct-2017 07:53:31 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ,,, on line 4
[02-Oct-2017 07:53:31 America/Denver] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in .... on line 5 COM extensão rodou redondo

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo você diz no php 5, em qual site online e você diz com qual extensão exatamente?

Comment: fopen — Abre um arquivo ou URL  `test` não é um ARQUIVO nem um URL

Comment: Entendi, tentei online com uma url e também persiste o mesmo erro. Todos testes que tenho feito, são em compiladores online

Comment: @rray só realizei testes com compiladores online.

Comment: Não vai funcionar pq não existe esse arquivo no servidor remote.